# How can i get 100x100 square picture from facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I need to get 100x100 square picture from facebook graph api. Picture must be croped like standart square "50x50" picture, but size must be 100x100. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The Graph API only* offers the following sizes (specify the picture size with the type argument):

- **square**: 50x50 pixels
- **small**: 50 pixels wide, variable height
- **normal**: 100 pixels wide, variable height
- **large**: about 200 pixels wide, variable height

If you want the image to be 100x100, you will have to retrieve the "normal" size and crop it yourself, e.g. if you are using php check the [imagecopyresampled](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) function

*** UPDATE**:

As pointed out in the comments below, this answer was correct in May 2012, but nowadays you also have the option to get different sizes using **graph.facebook.com/*`UID`*/picture?width=*`N`*&height=*`N`***, as described in the more recent answer from Jeremy.

Comment: You can get the picture in any dimensions you want, you're not limited to these four options. See @Jeremy's answer.

Comment: @LukaRamishvili: yes you are no longer limited to those 4 sizes. However they were the only options at the time of the original question, and this answer to the OP was accurate. Jeremy's answer was added after further options were added (in Aug 2012 I believe) and is valid now.

Comment: I see. Thanks for reminding me, I didn't look at the dates.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}


- (UIImage *)crop:(CGRect)rect andIm:(UIImage*) im {

    CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

    if (scale>1.0) {
        rect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x*scale , rect.origin.y*scale, rect.size.width*scale, rect.size.height*scale);
    }

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([im CGImage], rect);
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return result;
}

-(UIImage*)squareLargeFacebookProfilePhoto:(UIImage*) image{

    float startPosX=0.0;
    float startPosY=0.0;
    float newsizeW;
    float newsizeH;

    if (image.size.height>=image.size.width){
        newsizeW=200;
        float diff=200-image.size.width;
        newsizeH=image.size.height+diff/image.size.width*image.size.height;

        if (newsizeH>200){
            startPosY=(newsizeH-200.0)/8.0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        newsizeH=200;
        float diff=200-image.size.height;
        newsizeW=image.size.width+diff/image.size.height*image.size.width;

        if (newsizeW>200){
            startPosX=(newsizeW-200.0)/2.0;
        }
    }


    UIImage *imresized=[self imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(newsizeW, newsizeH)];
    return [self crop:CGRectMake(startPosX, startPosY, 200, 200) andIm:imresized];

}
```

The url https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/picture?type=square gives us a small
profile picture ( 50x50 )

1)First of all you have to download the image from the url:

https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/picture?type=large

For example Loading Images

```
NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/picture?type=large];
NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

2)Then simply call the function that will return the large Facebook profile picture of the  size ( 200x200 ):

```
UIImage *LargeProfileImage=[self squareLargeFacebookProfilePhoto:image];
```

Note: the code was written with use of ARC memory management

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

https://graph.facebook.com/INSERTUIDHERE/picture?width=100&height=100

DON'T FORGET to replace the 'INSERTUIDHERE' with the UID of the user you are trying to get an image for. Embedded ruby works great here. Ex: ...ook.com/<%= @problem.user.uid %>/pic...

Note that you can change the dimensions to be anything you want (ex: 50x50 or 500x500). It should crop and resize from the center of the photo. It (for some reason) is sometimes a few pixels larger or smaller, but I think that has more to do with the dimensions of the original photo. Yay first answer on SO!

Here's my stupid mug at 100 x 100 using the link above. I'd provide more, but SO is preventing posting multiple links since I'm a n00b.

100 x 100: https://graph.facebook.com/8644397/picture?width=100&height=100