# facebook graph api, feed and image dimension

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api

I import a Facebook page's feed via the graph api.
Example:

```
GET/VERSION/SECRET/feed?fields=created_time,picture
```

This works as expected, but every picture is just a <100x100px thumbnail.
How can i retrieve a bigger picture?

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638778/how-can-i-get-100x100-square-picture-from-facebook-graph-api), but I wonder if i can do everything in the GET call I've explained above.
Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34680293/1427878

Comment: wonderful. Thank you. I was using [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/post)  for reference but`full_picture` is not listed.